# Angular HttpClient POST request is not working in upLoadByFile method EditorJs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, editorjs

I am trying to integrate EditorJs into my Angular v10.1.7 app. But in the image configuration, I can not use POST request from Angular HttpClient to send the request to my server.

Here is the code :

```
    image: {
      class: ImageTool,
      config: {
        uploader: {
          uploadByFile(file) {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', file, this.title);
            this.httpClient.post(this.NEWS_URL + 'image', formData)
              .subscribe((res) => {
                return {
                  success: res.success,
                  url: res.url,
                };
              });
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

And the error:

```
Image Tool: uploading failed because of TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
```

How can I handle with this problem? Is there any alternative solution for sending file to server without using Angular HttpClient?

Comment: Can you show the constructor as well as the modules you're importing?

Comment: import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
// As well as modules of Editor.js //

constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {}